# Error running Metasploit Framework on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: metasploit

I have installed Metasploit Framework on Mac OS X Yosemite running Ruby 2.1.6 using the instructions [here](http://www.evilsocket.net/2015/01/16/how-to-install-metasploit-on-os-x-mavericks-and-yosemite-an-updated-guide/).

It gives me an error when I try to run it:

```
/usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse':     (/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in `block in load_file'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in `open'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in `load_file'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/ui/console/driver.rb:172:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `new'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in `driver'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in `start'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
from /usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/msfconsole:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/msfconsole:23:in `load'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/msfconsole:23:in `<main>'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usernames/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Is there any fix for this?